# Why did Syrena take Philip under water?

Tags: plot-explanation, pirates-of-the-caribbean, on-stranger-tides

At the end of *Pirates of the Caribbean: On Stranger Tides* (2011) we can see in Syrena (mermaid) and Philip having the below conversation:

> Syrena: You're hurt.
>
> Philip: Body, only. My mind is at peace - Cause of you.
>
> Syrena: Me?
>
> Philip: Yes. I was lost, the wind. The tides...They truly knew man's fate. For me, only you.
>
> Syrena: Philip, I can save you. You need only ask.
>
> Philip: I seek but one thing.
>
> Syrena: What is that?
>
> Philip: Forgiveness. If not for me you would never have been captured.
>
> Syrena: Ask!
>
> Philip: Forgive me.

After that Syrena kissed Philip and took him under water.

Why did she take Philip under water? Can Syrena save Philip under water?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can Syrena save Philip under water?

Yes, she can sort of save Phillip underwater.

When they start calling mermaids, Derrick says

> I heard it said that the kiss from a
>   mermaid can save a sailor from drowning.

<sub>[Source](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/movie_script.php?movie=pirates-of-the-caribbean-on-stranger-tides)</sub>

Though, this is never explained in the movie, but it's a legend popular among sailors that a mermaid kiss can save sailor from drowning as told by Derrick. If you remember, Syrena kissed Phillip before taking him underwater.

> why did Syrena take Philip Under water?

When Syrena asks him to just ask again, she probably meant that she forgave him and wants to be with him.

From this [SFF answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/27253/78187),

> I thought this meant that she wanted to do more than simply forgive him. **That she wanted to save him and be with him.** In some stories mermaids can grant the ability to breathe and thus live under water too. So I thought she took him into the sea to be with him happily ever after. Because she did not seem sad when she took him down.